# Google maps MarkerWithLabel CSS hover effect glitch

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I'm using MarkerWithLabel so that I can create Google Maps markers with div's to get effective CSS animations among other things.

The ability to use :hover in CSS was recently added a couple of months ago to the MarkerWithLabel library, but the event is only registered on parts of the marker as you can see in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/lantchips/pen/gPGZbR).

```
CSS
#container:hover { // Works but glitches
   opacity: 1.0;
}

JS
var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
  position: myMap.getCenter(),
  map: myMap,
  opacity: 0.0,
  labelContent: "<div id=container>" +
  " <div id=largeDiv" +
    (a lot of code)
  "></div>" +
  " <div id=smallDiv" +
    (a lot of code)
  "></div>" +
  "</div>",
  labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(width/2, height/2),
  labelClass: "labelClass" // the CSS class for the label
});
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this feature just buggy at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the default google maps marker that is causing the problem. 
There is a div positioned where your markers are and it contains the default google maps marker but it's not visible because it's opacity is set to 0. But if you hover over that area you notice that is where the `:hover` style isn't working and it appears buggy.

Try applying this to your css:

```
.gmnoprint {display:none !important}
```

I also noticed your comments in the css here:

```
#largeDiv { // Nothing happens
  opacity: 0.3;
}
#smallDiv { // Nothing happens
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

Nothing happens because you have used inline styles in your javascript and they overwrite styles from your css.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works exactly like I want it to do now! [codepen](http://codepen.io/lantchips/pen/YwEPJx)